# Model class is not found in zend framework project (quickstart)

Tags: zend-framework

The things I did is

1. zf create project demo1 in command prompt
2. add the lines to application.ini

   - appnamespace = "Application"
   - resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
3. add a layout with header and footer using partial() (They are perfectly worked)
4. create Data.php in models directory and add this simple class

   ```
   <?php class Application_Model_Data{   }//Application for appnamespace
   ```
5. then I tried to load this class(by creating instance)from index controller index action

   $data = new Application_Model_Data();
6. but when I test it even in this level it gives an error

   Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_Data' not found in C:\Zend\...\IndexController.php

**Question**

1. Do I want to add a autoloader to
   load models in the application( I'm not used modules)
2. if not what was I missed to add

please help I'm stuck in the beginning,Thank you

Comment: What version of ZF do you have? I did the quickstart and It worked perfectly

Comment: Yes,It's must be worked.Zend Server CE (PHP 5.3)Zend Framework Version  1.9.5.I think it's a problem of my code or the system..Thanks

Answer (score 4):

this should work!!

add this function to bootstrap:

```
protected function _initResourceAutoloader()
{
     $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => 'Application',
     ));

     $autoloader->addResourceType( 'model', 'models', 'Model');
     return $autoloader;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a resource Autoloader in your Bootstrap, something like this:

```
protected function _initResourceAutoloader()
{
     $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => 'path/to/application/directory',
        'namespace' => 'Application_',
     ));

     return $autoloader;
}
```

With that, Zend can load the modules in your application, and just not models, but DbTable, Forms, Plugins, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much.I tried it but nothing's changed.I think sth wrong in my app.thanks again

Answer (score 2):

write the following in your bootstrap file:

```
protected function _initDefaultModuleAutoloader()
{ 

    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));

    return $resourceLoader;

}
```

in your models folder create new file and name it "Data.php"

in the Data.php declare the class like this:

```
class Model_Data extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {.....}
```

you can now instantiate your data model like so:

```
$data = new Model_Data();
```

good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

in your application ini you should have
`autoloadernamespaces.0 = 'Application'` instead of **appnamespace**

then your model would be in

> /library/Application/Model/Data.php

but why dont you use the default "models" folder in the suggested application structure.

Comment: no no data.php file placed in default model folder
demo1\application\models\Data.php

Comment: /library/Application/Model/Data.php ? no no this is not a library class.it'a simple model class.Thanks

Comment: please help me,I know how to add DBs and table classes to application.my IDE show that class on the right location but I can't access model classes from controllers.why? please.Thanks

Comment: if the model is in the models folder, the class name is only Model_Data

Comment: I tried it but "Class 'Model_Data' not found in ....IndexController.php on line xx.

by the way thank you very much.

Comment: if all others fail (which shouldnt normaly) you always can extend your include path: includePaths.model = APPLICATION_PATH "models" (if APPLICATION_PATH points to demo1/application/)

Comment: thank you very much for still with me.I tried it also in the beginning,nothing's changed.I'm using Zend Server CE (PHP 5.3) with Win7,don't know Zend_Tool perfectly worked in this environment or I have missed sth to add.Also I run and test the Jeroen Keppens' modular application but it worked. sth wrong with my app.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add the file extension .php to the file, just in case someone else makes the same mistake